# Spanish language encoding issue with Java Properties class load method

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to encode the Spanish language for internationalization and use the Java Properties class load method to populate it to pass it to frontend.

I have tried to encode it using UTF-8 but still the accent characters are not coming correctly.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Message extends Properties {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String spanish = "label=Sí";
        Message messages = new Message();
        messages.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(spanish.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));

        System.out.println(messages.get("label"));

    }

}
```

When i run the above code I am getting the text as "SÃ­-". How can I retrieve the same text as "Sí"?

Comment: You say you're "getting it"--how, exactly, on the terminal? That usually means your terminal is misconfigured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ISO-8859-1 it gets expected result:

```
 messages.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(spanish.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))));
```

More about ISO-8859-1 can be obtained from this link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Comment: Converting a Unicode string to ISO-8859-1 is a lossy operation. If the detour of reading a string (instead of just calling `messages.put("label", "Sí");`) really is required, then, the correct solution would be to use `messages.load(new StringReader(spanish));` which never leaves the world of Unicode text.

Comment: I agree with your objection, dear Holger, and you are completely right, so if OP sees it and is willing to go for editing a code, this is even better approach. @Holger